# What is time complexity of this algorithm as Big-O notation?

Tags: c, algorithm

This is a algorithm for this question: Rotate a array of n elements left by i positions. For instance, with n = 8 and i = 3, the array abcdefg is rotated to defghabc.

```
/* Alg 1: Rotate by reversal */

void reverse(int i, int j)
{   int t;
    while (i < j) {
        t = x[i]; x[i] = x[j]; x[j] = t;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
}

void revrot(int rotdist, int n)
{   reverse(0, rotdist-1);
    reverse(rotdist, n-1);
    reverse(0, n-1);
}
```

What is the time complexity of this method? And is there any better solution to this problem?
Thanks indeed.

Comment: O(2n), so O(n). You could surely do it in a pure O(n) time.

Comment: @ B Mitch . not homework. it's an example from a book. I just want to dig it deep.

Comment: @BMitch Nooo... It's the first piece of Skynet!

Comment: Maybe you could try asking the same question at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/  Seems like a better suited forum.

Comment: @xanatos - not without using O(n) memory. And even then, it's only "pure O(n)" if you don't do it in place. The nice thing about this algorithm is that it uses O(1) memory and it's done in place.

Comment: @xanatos- You're correct, but your notation is a bit messy.  O(2n) and O(n) are completely identical, while saying "pure O(n)" doesn't really mean anything.  Big-O notation talks about asymptotic growth, not the precise number of steps done.  A better way to say this would be "`revrot` performs 2n swaps, while it's possible to solve this problem using only n swaps."

Comment: @templatetypedef - you made me curious :). Could you tell how you'd do this with only `n` swaps?

Comment: @grz: No. cstheory is for research level questions. This is basic homework.

Comment: good discussion guys. Anyone can raise a "n swap" solution?

Comment: @Moron - if you mean the last solution here: http://www.rawkam.com/?p=1008 - then isn't that technically zero swaps?

Comment: @IVlad: Not sure exactly what definition of swap you have in mind. But yes, I was talking about the one where you decompose into cycles, and put the elements of the cycles in place by a sequence of swaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be roughly linear `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

The loop has to go for no more than (i+j)/2 times.  Dropping the constant, O(i+j).

Answer (score 0):

Big-O notation:

n is always O(n). (loops, as they have to go through several iterations)

1 so O(1). (if statement, specified quantity)

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, it'd O(n) since we're merely shifting.

As a food for thought, another possible algorithm is to make a new array with the original appended to itself (ie. abcd --> abcdabcd). Then shift the pointers right n times! Of course, you'll need two pointers, one for the end, one for the beginning. Remember to cut off the end with '\0'

Same run time btw.